# How ContentChild variable is used in tutorial

Tags: angular5

I'm following a tutorial from the book Angular 5 Projects and have a question on one of the exercises.

I don't know why the contentChild variable has to be instantiated and how it is used in the code.

```
ContentChild(CardComponent) contentChild: CardComponent;
```

Can someone please explain that?

Below is the code:

```
import { Component, ContentChild, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styles: []
 })
 export class CardComponent {

 }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <card>{{card}}</card>
    <button (click)="pickCard($event)">Pick a Card</button>
  `,
  styles: []
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterContentChecked {
  card = CARD_ACE_OF_SPADES;

  @ContentChild(CardComponent) contentChild: CardComponent;

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    console.log("content inside card has been checked: " + this.card);
  }

  pickCard() 
  {
    this.card = this.card === CARD_ACE_OF_SPADES ? CARD_TEN_OF_CLUBS : 
                                  CARD_ACE_OF_SPADES;        
  }  
}

const CARD_ACE_OF_SPADES = 'ace of spades';
const CARD_TEN_OF_CLUBS = 'ten of clubs';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be `@ViewChild`.

*ViewChild* ==> Selectors directly used in a component template.

*ContentChild* ==> Selectors used in `<ng-content>` selections.

---

For example:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'first-comp',
    template: `
        <card1></card1>
        <ng-conent></ng-content>
    `
})
export class FirstComponent {
    @ViewChild(Card1Component) card1: Card1Component;
    @ContentChild(Card2Component) card2: Card2Component;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'second-comp',
    template: `
        <first-comp>
            <card2></card2>
        </first-comp>
    `
})
export class SecondComponent {
    @ViewChild(FirstComponent) firstComp: FirstComponent;
    @ViewChild(Card2Component) card2: Card2Component;
}
```